# Want a commandline to get the data as it is as we get when we export data

Tags: plsql, plsqldeveloper, toad, spool

I have a data that is having some thousands of records and each record having multiple columns.One of the column is having a data where there is a punctuation mark `","` in it.

When I had tried to spool that data into a csv file and text to columns data using the delimters as comma,the data seems to be inappropriate as the data itself has a comma in it.

I am looking for a solution where I can export the data using a command line which is having as it is look when I export the data via `TOAD`.

Any help is much appreciated.

**Note:** I was looking for this solution since many days but got a chance now to post it here.

Comment: Any earliest help is much appraciated

Answer (score 0):

When exporting the dataset in Toad, select a delimiter other than a comma or drop down the "string quoting" dropdown box and select "double quote strings including NULLS".

Oh wait if you are spooling output, you'll need to add the double-quotes in your select statement like this in order to surround the columns containing the comma with double-quotes:

```
select '"' || column || '"' as column from table;
```

This format is pretty standard but use pipes as delimiters instead and save  space by not having to wrap strings in double-quotes.  Depends on what the consumer of the data requires really.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Gary.I was actually looking for large set of data which has commas in it and we do use a `select * from tablename` instead..Let me rephrase my query..I do not wanted to use toad for exporting data..but I wanted to use the command line options like spool to get the output exactly like when extracted from toad.

Comment: Yes you'll need to replace the `SELECT *` with a column list (best practice anyway) and surround the columns likely to contain commas with quotes.  I'll amend my example above to better show it.

Comment: Gary_W , I would have replaced the * with multiple columns..but as the column list is more,i may not be able to use the option.My aim is to get the output same into a csv format which is exactly same as the excel output when extracted via `TOAD`.

Comment: Any suggestions on above? Need this to fulfill one of my requirement in automating the work

Comment: I know its tedious, but you need to get the quotes around the fields.  Just select in the order you need for the csv.  If this is something you'll repeat, you could make it a function that reads the all_tab_cols table and outputs the select you need maybe. could be an interesting exercise.

Comment: Thank you for the reply..Thought there would be some easy way to achieve this. For suppose I am having 5 columns in my data..in which column 2 has data with more characters, and when I tried to extract the data using `spool`,I am just getting till 2 columns and rest of the columns are getting vanished. Is there any way to get all the columns. I tried amending the `linesize` but with no luck.

Comment: You'll have to edit your original post and include the actual data before/after.  Include the code so we can see what you are doing.